# Responsive design: How to resize images/background images and align divs vertically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am experimenting with responsive design. My images are not currently resizing. In my markup, I also have background images applied to certain divs which needs to be resized.

Here is the HTML view: http://jsbin.com/emojeg/2

See the code here: http://jsbin.com/emojeg/2/edit

For screen width between 800px and 1100px, I'd like to resize the images. For anything below 800px, I'd like to align the picture frames vertically - 1 or 2 per row whatever the screen width permits.

Currently when I resize the browser to the narrower width, up to 2 of the frames wrap to the next row but if I keep resizing further, the picture frame's background seems to cut off and some of the images seem to disappear. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Actually, you aren't resizing the images, are you? When I narrow my explorer I can't see resizing, just image movements

Comment: @Chococroc In the above url, no I haven't resized. I tried resizing it in another version but I have other issues with my absolute divs etc which I am finding it hard to convert into responsive.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure, in this example you just want to make sure that all get into columns when resizing, but what you want to achieve is columns + resizing, is that right?

Comment: @Chococroc Well basically on wider screens, when resized, I want the frames and backgrounds to resize proportionally. On mobile landscape orientation, I want all the four picture frames to show up at once. On mobile portrait orientation, I want to have the slider converted to one item at a time. I know this will probably need adjustment to the HTML markup itself. I may have to recreate the layout. I'm just not sure how to approach this - whether media queries is going to be enough or if I need to use jQuery to do this or have a totally different HTML file loaded for mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your images and backgrounds to resize correctly I'd suggest the following changes.

First set your image width and height with percentages, allowing enough space for the frame around the edges, and use `position:relative` to add a percentage offset from the top rather than setting a margin. You don't need to worry about the horizontal position, since it's already centered, unless you want to adjust it a little to account for the fact that your frame image isn't perfectly even.

```
ul.mrpv_slider li div img {
    position:relative;
    top:11%;
    width:67%;
    height:78%;
}
```

Then add `background-size:100% 100%` to the *image_container* so the background image for the frame resizes to match the container as well.

```
ul.mrpv_slider li div.image_container { 
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url(http://i36.tinypic.com/5feusn.png);
    background-position:bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-right:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    height:324px;
    width:250px;

    /* this is the line you need to add */
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

At that point, you can override the *width* and *height* of the container in your media queries and the images and frames will all adjust themselves appropriately.

I'm not exactly sure what you intended to do with the layout as the window size changed, but your current media query that sets the width to 100% and height to auto is definitely not going to work.

As an example though, you could make the images half size when the screen is less than 600px wide with a query like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    ul.mrpv_slider li div.image_container {
        height:162px
        width:125px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't had chance to test it on my code yet but it has given me some insight.

Answer (score 5):

It's because that slider you're using has loads of absolute positioning and fixed widths/heights. I'd recommend using something that is actually responsive, like Flexslider (http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)

But if you don't want to do that, you can remove the position:relative and the fixed height from the .mrpv_container class --

```
.mrpv_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 710px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The rest of the CSS would probably have to be cleaned up also, but does that give the desired effect?

Comment: About the Flexislider, no I can't use it as what I am trying to achieve is a bit different. Your CSS suggestion seems to work to some extent. It aligns the the divs vertically in narrower browser width. I think I still need to do some cleaning up to give it a better look. Do you know how why my images and background images aren't resizing?

Comment: One more thing... What if I want to create a different markup for mobile displays - how do I do that? For instance, on mobile devices, if I want to display one picture frame at a time instead of 4, I will have to change the entire markup. How do I achieve this? I don't think it can be done with media queries alone. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: What is the effect you're trying to achieve? And if you want your images to resize, you have to remove the max-width:100% from the img {} CSS and change it to just width: 100%. And as for the mobile thing, am I correct in thinking that you want it to be a four-up slider on desktops, but only show one item at a time for mobile?

Comment: Changing `max-width` to `width` does not seem to work in this case. It seems to blow up the image. I think it's because the image's parent div has a fixed width set. But if I don't set it to a fixed width or height, the background image won't appear. I am still unable to get my head around this. In my example, there are some background images apart from just images.

Comment: Yes you are right about the mobile thing. On wider screens, I want all the four picture frames to show up at once but on narrow screen (mobile with portrait display), I want to have the slider converted to one item at a time. I know this will probably need adjustment to the HTML markup itself. I may have to recreate the layout. I'm just not sure how to approach this - whether media queries is going to be enough or if I need to use jQuery to do this or have a totally different HTML file loaded for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I too have been experimenting with responsive design and found Twitter's "Bootstrap" to be amazingly helpful. It's only 3 files and I build all my sites with it. Check it out if you haven't already: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Yes I initially wanted to use bootstrap but thought it would be easier without it since my slider has many absolute positioning with different layers. If nothing else works, I might have to revisit bootstrap again.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have used twitter bootstrap as well as http://responsiveimg.com/ for making images responsive and fix the aspect ratio as well according to the screen and image size.

If you are using an image slider then jquery bxslider is also very helpful